# Zend, organization and MVC

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm a beginner, and I have a question concerning the organization in Zend (with the Model View Controller architecture).

Already, the explanation ...
Let's say I have an object "**$subject**" (Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract) on which the objects "**$member**" (Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract) could subscribe.
If I turn off the **$subject** (**$subject->disable()**) in question, members are expected to receive an email ...

My question is, where should I do the manipulations (find members subscribers, send them an email, notifications, ...).
For now I do it in disable() function in my class Subject, you see. And I do not think this is really the right way to do (although this may work) ...

Would you have ideas, answer ... ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago, I did the same thing.
I created a model class EmailsOut and I called it from the controller

```
CREATE TABLE `emails_out` (
    `id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `body` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `from` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `to` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    `cc` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    `bcc` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ready',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
```

In your model **EmailsOut.php**

```
class MyApp_Model_DbTable_EmailsOut extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'emails_out';
}
```

In your controller

```
public function turnOffAction() {

    // Creation of your $subject object.

    // Disabling the subject
    $subject->disable();

    //Sending the email
    $tEmailsOut = new MyApp_Model_DbTable_EmailsOut();
    $email = $tEmailsOut->createRow();
    $email->subject ="This is the subject";
    $email->body = "This is the body";
    $email->from = "mr.x@gmail.com|Mr. X";
    $email->to = "mr.y@gmail.com|Mr. Y";
    $email->save();

    // The rest of the function
}
```

Then, I had a cron job sending out all emails every minutes